# GoalSeek to loop through rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through rows.  The ranges I need to loop through are in columns B (Set Cell) and G (Changing Cell) and start from row 18.  The loop needs to go through a set number of rows, the number of which is found as an integer in Cell "F9" i.e. Cell F9 could contain 22.  The "To value" will always be 0.

Essentially, the numbers in Col B need to get to 0.0 by recalculating the % in Col G.

[image]

It's important to note that the number of rows are dynamic and could exceed what is in the image I uploaded.

I used the following for a GoalSeek on Columns where the "To Value" was also dynamic.  I can't figure out how to convert this to my current requirements.

```
Private Sub GoalSeek()
    
    Dim k As Long
    Dim ResultCell As Range
    Dim ChangingCell As Range
    Dim TargetFTE As Range
    
    Dim controlCell As Integer
    controlCell = Range("C15").Value
    
    For k = 5 To (5 + controlCell)

        Set ResultCell = Cells(167, k)
        Set TargetFTE = Cells(173, k)
        Set ChangingCell = Cells(125, k)
        ResultCell.GoalSeek TargetFTE, ChangingCell

    Next k
  
End Sub
```

Comment: With the Solver? set a cell to be the sum of col B, then that is the objective with the changing cells from Col G.Set integer and other constraints as needed - like col G between 0 & 100.

Answer (score 1):

Found a working solution.

```
Sub GoalSeek_productivity()
'Defining variable k
Dim k As Integer
'Defining number of loops
Dim controlCell As Integer
controlCell = Range("F9").Value
'We are looping through each row in our table based on value in the controlCell minus 9 as the last number always needs to be 100%
    For k = 25 To (25 + controlCell - 9)
        'Below is how we replicate the Goal Seek functionality via VBA
        Range("B" & k).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("G" & k)
    'Go to next iteration
    Next k    
End Sub
```